# Minimize RDP-session from within the session

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

Is it possible using C# to switch to local machine from an RDP session, eg. simulating Ctrl+Alt+Break from within the session?

I've tried InputSimulator and Sendkeys without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. The machine inside the rdp window has no concept of being in an rdp session.

The reason ctrl-alt-del works from the keyboard is because the rdp application listens redirects all inputs into the session.